# Android - Tabbed Navigation in Landscape Orientation

Tags: android, layout, tabs, landscape, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We are building an Android 4.0 app with tabbed navigation at the top.  This all works great in portrait mode but when the application changes to landscape mode (which we want to support), the default behaviour is for the tabs to move up into the top/action bar which seems to eliminate the ability to have a screen title shown and seems crowded with the actions that appear on the right of the top/action bar.

What is the best approach to prevent this and how difficult would it be to override this default behaviour?

Comment: Are you using a TabLayout or an ActionBar ?

Comment: Actionbar.  Would using a TabLayout lend itself more to landscape orientations?

Comment: It's actually part of Android's best practice to use the ActionBar. I don't have much experience with it however, so I can't really answer your question.

Comment: TabLayout exhibits the behavior you are looking for, although as @Jean-PhilippeRoy mentioned, the ActionBar is recommended by Google as the best practice.